# Find the indices of similar elements in numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a numpy array that has different values in it some of which could be equal. I want to return a list of lists that each list contains the indices of equal elements. For example, imagine

```
A=np.array([2,3,2,1,1,1,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,3])
```

Then the result I want should be

```
[[0,2],[1,6,13],[3,4,5],[7],[8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

here is my solution but I am looking for a smarter way to do it:

```
h=[]
s=set()
for i in list_name:

    if i in s:
        continue
    h.append(np.where(list_name==i))
    s.add(i)

print h
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the order doesn't matter, this should work.

```
import numpy as np
input_array = np.array([2,3,2,1,1,1,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,3])
out_array = [np.where(input_array == element)[0].tolist() for element in np.unique(input_array)]
```

When I run this, I get

```
[[3, 4, 5], [0, 2], [1, 6, 13], [7], [8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: If order does impact it, `out_array = [np.where(in_array == element)[0].tolist() for element in in_array]` plus `np.unique(np.array(out_array))`

Comment: Your solution is O(n^2), which is inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Try finding unique elements in the array using np.unique [1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

Loop over this array using np.where  [2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).
Example to find all indices with element 0 is

numpy.where(x == 0)[0]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hashmap. The key can be an int in the array, and the value can be a linked list that stores the indices of that int.

Loop through the array and for every int in the array, add its index to the hashmap.

At the end, retrieve those indices from the lists in the map.

Answer (score 1):

A lookup table could do this nicely, then you can look them up explicitly:

```
mytable = {}

for i, value in enumerate(list_name):
    mytable[value] = [i, *mytable.get(value,[])]

mytable.get(2)
[0,2]
```

And if you just want the indices, then:

```
indices = [mytable.get(a) for a in list_name]

[[0,2],[1,6,13],[3,4,5],[7],[8],[9,10,11,12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a NumPy solution, but it does the trick (and applies to NumPy arrays too).

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3]
positions = defaultdict(set)

for index, value in enumerate(a):
    positions[value].add(index)

print(dict(positions))
```

outputs

```
{2: {0, 2}, 3: {1, 13, 6}, 1: {3, 4, 5}, 4: {7}, 5: {8}, 6: {9, 10, 11, 12}}
```

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

Kinda ugly having to do unique at the end but worked

```html
import numpy as np
A=np.array([2,3,2,1,1,1,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,3])

def index(my_list, element):
        return [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == element]
print np.unique(np.array([index(A,i) for i in A]))

>> [[0, 2] [1, 6, 13] [3, 4, 5] [7] [8] [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```